# ADK installation Windows 7 Home premium 64 bit OS

Tags: android, framework-installation

I am using MS Windows 7 Home Premium. 64 Bit OS.

I am just wondering, can I install Android Development kit on this system.

Thanks
FArid

Answer (score 3):

Yep, it works just fine on my setup. (Windows 7 64 bit)

**Edit:** Here is some evidence to back me up: http://forums.t-mobile.com/t5/Operating-System-Software/Android-SDK-and-Windows-7/td-p/332452